# How to check if a text input is empty (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, text, field, alert, getelementbyid

I'm actually working on a school project (it is my first year, i'm not very advanced yet), and I struggle a bit with my code... here it is:

```
function message() {
  if (document.getElementById("ch2").checked == true) {
    window.alert("Transaction confirmée... Une facture vous sera postée")
  } else if (document.getElementById("ch2").checked != true) {
    if (document.getElementById("prenom") == "") {
      prenom = false;
      prenomF = ("Prénom absent \n")
    } else if (document.getElementById("prenom") != "") {
      prenom = true;
      prenomF = ""
    }
    if (document.getElementById("nom") == "") {
      nom = false;
      nomF = ("Nom absent \n")
    } else if (document.getElementById("nom") != "") {
      nom = true;
      nomF = ""
    }
    if (document.getElementById("nocivique") == "") {
      nocivique = false;
      nociviqueF = ("Numéro civique absent \n")
    } else if (document.getElementById("nocivique") != "") {
      nocivique = true;
      nociviqueF = ""
    }
    if (document.getElementById("rue") == "") {
      rue = false;
      rueF = ("Rue absente \n")
    } else if (document.getElementById("rue") != "") {
      rue = true;
      rueF = ""
    }
    if (document.getElementById("ville") == "") {
      ville = false;
      villeF = ("Ville absente \n")
    } else if (document.getElementById("ville") != "") {
      ville = true;
      villeF = ""
    }
    if (document.getElementById("code") == "") {
      code = false;
      codeF = ("Code postal absent \n")
    } else if (document.getElementById("code") != "") {
      code = true;
      codeF = ""
    }
    if (prenom == false || nom == false || nocivique == false || rue == false || ville == false || code == false) {
      window.alert(prenomF + nomF + nociviqueF + rueF + villeF + codeF)
    } else if (prenom == true && nom == true && nocivique == true && rue == true && ville == true && code == true) {
      carte = window.prompt("Entrez votre numéro de carte de crédit:");
      window.alert("Transaction confirmée... portée à la carte " + carte)
    }
  }
}
```

So the problem is, when I click the button that runs this function (without entering anything in the text fields), it asks me for my credit car... which is supposed to happen only if none of the fields are empty. I can't make it pop up the window.alert even if the fields are empty, which means they all have a value of ("") I guess... also, I added an onload function which sets the default value of the boxes to (""), in order to get it working: but it doesn't. So if anyone could help me, I was thinking about replacing the:

```
if(document.getElementById("prenom") == "") {/*something here*/}
```

by something that checks if the text fields is empty.

Comment: You need to compare the value of the input.

Comment: getElementById returns an actual Object (assuming that there is a match).  That object is never going to be equivalent to "".  You want to do `document.getElementById("prenom").value`

Comment: Oh my god it's actually that simple ahahah thank you man! Dumb mistake, I see now what was the problem... worked very well! Thank you!!